# Instantiate a python object according to class string stored in db- recommended design pattern?

Tags: python, postgresql, design-patterns

Is this a suggested practice to save object type (as string) in db (postgresql) and instantiate the object after loading the name of the object from the db?
if not- what is the suggested design pattern?

The configuration refers to some logic encapsulated in the object (the logic cannot be stored in the db...).

In other words- what is the recommended design pattern for different code which should be executed according to some value in the db...

Thanks

Comment: Storing classnames in the database is usually bad practice. You should just store a logical name in the database & map it to a class in the application

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate why? or add reference?

Comment: Think about what you would have to do if you want to change the name of the class. Or move it to some other package. Seemingly simple tasks might end up requiring a DB migration. Or enforce undue restrictions on what you can & cannot do in your code - because your database is tied up to your code base now.

Comment: You can check this for a more detailed explanation: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205196/good-practice-storing-variables-and-classes-names-in-database-for-direct-call